# Understand pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm reviewing my C skills, and I'm struggling to understand some bits.
Here's my understanding of C and pointers.

Every time I declare a variable, C stores the value in memory.

```
int num = 12; // The 12 is stored somewhere in memory, let's say has address 0x54
```

To get the memory address of variable "num" we do:

```
printf("%p", &num); // this returns the 0x54
```

if I want to create a pointer, that points to the same value of "num", I do:

```
int *ptr = &num; // create a pointer and point him to 0x54
```

If I check both address:

```
printf("%p\n", &num); // prints 0x54
printf("%p\n", ptr); // prints 0x54
printf("%p\n", &ptr); // prints 0x94 is the address of the pointer itself
```

**After the above...**
I don't understand the output of my program.
I'm reading this [book](https://learncodethehardway.org/c/), and the author says that we can treat pointers as arrays and vice versa (except in some cases [if I understood correctly]).

```
int ages[] = { 23, 43, 12, 89, 2 };

printf("1-%d\n", ages[0]);
printf("1-%d\n", ages[1]);

printf("2-%p\n", &ages[0]);
printf("2-%p\n", ages);
printf("2-%p\n", &ages);

printf("3-%d\n", *(&ages[1]));
printf("4-%p\n", *(&ages));
printf("5-%p\n", &ages[1]);
printf("6-%p\n", &ages+1);
printf("7-%d\n", *(*(&ages)+1));
printf("8-%ld\n", sizeof(1));
```

**Output with questions in comments:**

```
1-23 // value of position 0, OK
1-43 // value of position 1, OK
2-0x7fff1fd500f0 // adress of the beginning of array, OK
2-0x7fff1fd500f0 // same as above, OK
2-0x7fff1fd500f0 // because ages is not a pointer, same as above, OK
3-43 // get address of ages, advance 4 bytes and then give me the value that is in that address, OK
4-0x7fff1fd500f0 // give me the address of ages, and then give the value that is in that address. The address I have in the print number 2, why doesn't return the value and show me the address? **NOT OK**
5-0x7fff1fd500f4 // give me the address of the position 1 of the array, the address that contains the number 43, OK
6-0x7fff1fd50104 // why I don't get the same number of the print 5? How I jump from f0 to 104? **NOT OK**
7-43 // why I need pointer of pointer, **NOT OK**
8-4 // this was just trying to understand print 6, OK
```

Can someone explain me prints 4, 6 and 7, and let me know if I'm thinking correctly on the other prints.

Comment: If somebody tells you that arrays and pointers are the same, run away. C11 draft standard n1570: *6.3 Conversions 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the
unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points
to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has
register storage class, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: If you understand `printf("2-%p\n", &ages);`, then I don't quite get what's confusing about the rest.

Comment: @EOF As it should be. The pointer/array parallel is a dark relic of our past and has no place in today's society other than to illustrate a historic mistake.

Comment: @Ouroborus: Not at all. The C standard is very clear about what arrays and pointers are, and how they relate. If people like you stopped mystifying the subject and simply explained it correctly, there would be no problem.

Comment: @EOF: The point he's trying to make is that you *shouldn't rely* on such things. You should structure your code so that you *avoid* doing them. That way, you never have this question come up, and you don't require people to know about these pointless corners of the language.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Pointers and arrays are effectively unavoidable in C (Note that this question is tagged `c`, not just `c++`, and the title contains `c`, not `c++`. What Ouroborus is doing is just as bad as what the bad book the OP is using is doing. Both are actively hurting the understanding of the issue by spreading misinformation and FUD.

Comment: @EOF: I didn't suggest avoiding pointers or arrays. I suggested that you should avoid circumstances where the behavior of an array type is not *obvious*, without having deep understanding about when and how one decays into the other.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It is *always* obvious once you understand the very simple rules set out in the language standard. Which comments like Ouroboros' only serve to dissuade people from. Conversely, if people *don't* know the rules, they get surprised at every turn and conclude that C is "too hard" or arrays/pointers are "a dark relic of our past".

Comment: @NicolBolas: Using constructs of **any** language requires understanding what that construct does. For natural languages there might be ways around as they are ambigous and imprecise anyway. But this is not true for programming languages. And as EOF wrote, the beahviour and coercison of arrays etc. is well defined by the language. Mystifying it does not help a beginner. But that seems to be common practice of teachers who have themselves not really understood the relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusions all boil down to two things: how operator precedence works and what `&ages` means.

Let's look at the latter first. Obviously `&ages` is a pointer. But what is it a pointer *to*? It's not a pointer to `int`. Instead, it's a pointer to the type `int[5]`.

So let's look at this:

> ```
> printf("4-%p\n", *(&ages));
> ```

If you have a pointer to `int[5]`, and you use `*` on it, you get what it points to: `int[5]`. This then decays to a pointer when being passed to `printf`. Specifically, a pointer to the first element of the array.

This:

> ```
> printf("5-%p\n", &ages[1]);
> ```

Is a matter of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Using explicit parenthesis, this is `&(ages[1])`; `[]` has higher precedence than `&`. Well, we know that `ages[1]` is the second `int` in the array. Using `&` on it will return a pointer to the second element in the array.

In a similar way:

> ```
> printf("6-%p\n", &ages+1);
> ```

Operator precedence tells us that this is really `(&ages) + 1`. And remember, what is `&ages`? That's right, a pointer to `int[5]`.

When we perform pointer arithmetic, we add the size of the object being pointed to to the address. That object is `int[5]`, whose size is 20. Or in hex, 0x14. Therefore, you get an address 0x14 bytes from the start of the array.

As for:

> ```
> printf("7-%d\n", *(*(&ages)+1));
> ```

Operator precedence tells us that this expression is really `*((*(&ages)) + 1)`. So you get a pointer to `int[5]`, turn it back into an `int[5]`, then add 1 to it. That requires decaying the `int[5]` into an `int*`, then using pointer arithmetic. Then you access the value at that address.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is not just an address, it's an address with an associated type, which has a size.

Thus when you increment a pointer to array type, it skips the whole array.

Another issue in the code is array decay, where an expression that denotes an array, such as `a` or `*&a`, decays to a pointer to the first item of the array.

It's an unfortunate implicit conversion that made sense at the time of early C.

In C++ it causes much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

arrays are too much efficient but the overhead of an array is the size which cannot be changed at runtime.

pointer is a variable of some type which has its address and type of data it points to eg:

```
//int* iPtr = 7; error pointers stores addresses not values
int* iPtr = 0x00000000 //(NULL) points to this address (correct);
```

above a pointer points to an integer is initialized to point to 0x00000000 which is NULL

```
int a  = 7;
int* iPtr = &a;
cout << "a: " << a << endl; // printing value of a; result is a: 7
cout << "&a: " << &a << endl; // printing address of a: result is: &a: 0x0018FF44
cout << "iPtr: " << iPtr << endl; // printing the address iPtr points to as you guess it is the address of a so the result: iPtr: 0x0018FF44

cout << "*iPtr: " << *iPtr << endl; // printing the value stored in the address the iPtr points to so the result is as you guess: *iPtr: 7
```

the powerful use of pointers: they are too much flexible but dangerous they can point to an array, variable, changing the address, size at runtime...
they are used by linked-list, oop (polymorphism...)

*** don't mess with pointers

Answer (score -1):

For #4, it's likely the result of compiler optimization. Taking the address and then immediately dereferencing the resulting pointer is effectively a no-op, so the optimizer's likely simply eliding those operations leaving just `ages` as the argument and that's the value you're seeing.

For #6, you're finding the address of the `ages` array and adding 1 to it, which in pointer arithmetic means "add 1 * the size of the variable pointed at". A 5-element array, assuming 4-byte integers, is 20 bytes long and if you check 0x7FFF1FD500F0 + 0x14 you get the result 0x7FFF1FD50104 that you see.

An array isn't a pointer, exactly. It acts a lot like one, but &(ages) isn't identical to &(ages[0]). Both have the same apparent value, but the former is a pointer to a 4-byte integer and the latter is a pointer to a 20-byte array of 4-byte integers. You have to keep that in mind when working with pointers to array elements, remembering to take the address of an element when you want to work within the array and need eg. the address of element 0 of the array and not the address of the array itself.

Comment: *"For #4, it's likely the result of compiler optimization."* That's not correct.